# How to get Developer Exception page to show multiple lines of code around exception?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.developerexceptionpageoptions states that a `DeveloperExceptionPageOptions` object can be passed as a parameter to `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` and one of the properties on the options object is `SourceCodeLineCount`.  Specifically, it says that the `SourceCodeLineCount` property:

> Determines how many lines of code to include before and after the line of code present in an exception's stack frame. Only applies when symbols are available and source code referenced by the exception stack trace is present on the server.

But when I put the following code in the `Configure` method of the startup.cs class:

```
 app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage( new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions() { SourceCodeLineCount = 10} );
```

The output in the Developer Exception Page doesn't appear to show the 20 lines of source code that it's suppose to.

[image]

**How does one get the Developer Exception page to show multiple lines of code around exception?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're still having this problem or not, but have you tried browsers other than IE? When I'm running in Chrome, I'm seeing a little [+] symbol on the left of each line number, that can be used to expand each snippet of code.

The line that the error occurs is highlighted in red, and the SourceCodeLineCount value (in my case, set to 2) is used to display the number of lines above the line that caused your exception.

See sample screenshot below. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Yep, your right the + char is now visible in Edge as well and the feature works as documented.  (I'm now using ASP.NET Core 2.2.  When I posted the questions I was using 1.x and there were no + chars to expand the listing (as can been seen from my screenshot) and the setting didn't adjust the number of source lines shown.  Bit the feature appears to be working well now.  Thanks for letting me know.